# DependencyObject DateTime Format Change

Tags: wpf, datepicker, dependency-properties, datetime-format

I am using a custom datepicker and i am trying to change the dateformat to show Year only via a dependency property. After some experiments i got a `Nullable object must have a value` exception. I am using the code below:

```
 public bool YearOnly
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(YearOnlyProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(YearOnlyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty YearOnlyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("YearOnly",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomizableDatePicker),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false, new PropertyChangedCallback(OnYearOnlyChanged)));

    private static void OnYearOnlyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        CustomizableDatePicker control = (CustomizableDatePicker)d;
        control.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(control.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy"));
    }
```

to change the date format and obviously it doesn't work.

I am using it from the `DatePicker` as: `YearOnly="True"`.

On the other hand using the `Style` below formats the `DatePicker` great:

```
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DatePickerTextBox}">
    <Setter Property="Control.Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <TextBox x:Name="PART_TextBox"
                    Text="{Binding Path=SelectedDate, StringFormat='yyyy', 
                    RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}" />
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Is there a way to make this work? Thanks.

Comment: The SelectedDate property is a `Nullable<DateTime>`. You have to check its `HasValue` property before accessing its `Value` (in OnYearOnlyChanged).

Comment: Thanks. I don't have the error now...but saddly the dateformat doesn't work.

Comment: The `OnYearOnlyChanged` callback is only called once, when the `YearOnly` property changes. If `SelectedDate` changes later, there seems to be no code that adjusts it.

Comment: That's what i've also noticed. Can you suggest a workaround?

Comment: You may add another property that holds the `SelectedYear`. Add a PropertyChangedCallback for `SelectedDate` via OverrideMetadata and set SelectedYear whenever SeletedDate changes. Set it to `SelectedDate.Value.Year` to avoid the formatting and conversion code.

Comment: actually even `control.SelectedDate = Convert.ToDateTime(control.SelectedDate.Value.ToString("yyyy"));` produces a parsing exception.

Comment: You shouldn't parse anything in the first place. Set `control.SelectedDate = new DateTime(control.SelectedDate.Value.Year, 0, 0);`

Comment: `Year, Month and Day parameters describe an un-representable DateTime`...everything is going wrong.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to write `new DateTime(control.SelectedDate.Value.Year, 1, 1);`

Comment: some sample code would help for your `SelectedYear` implementation proposal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hours of testing possible solutions, i came to the conclusion that a `DatePicker` would never accept a `DateTime` that only has `Year`. I (short of) implemented the solution that @Clemens suggested hoping to find a solution at some point for a `DatePicker` that accepts YearOnly `DateTime`s. Anyway the code i used is bellow for anyone interested. If anyone has another solution for my problem please add an Answer to this Question.

```
   private void CustomizableDatePicker_SelectedDateChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.YearOnly)
            return;

        this.SetValue(SelectedYearProperty, SelectedDate.Value.Year);

        Binding bnd = new Binding
        {
            Path = new PropertyPath("SelectedDate"),
            StringFormat = ("yyyy"),
            RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(CustomizableDatePicker), 1)
        };
        this.innerTextBox.SetBinding(TextBox.CustomizableTextBox.TextProperty, bnd);
    }
```

.................

```
 #region YearOnly DependencyProperty

    public bool YearOnly
    {
        get { return (bool)this.GetValue(YearOnlyProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(YearOnlyProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty YearOnlyProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("YearOnly",
        typeof(bool),
        typeof(CustomizableDatePicker),
        new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(false));

    #endregion

    #region SelectedYear DependencyProperty

    public int SelectedYear
    {
        get { return (int)this.GetValue(SelectedYearProperty); }
        set { this.SetValue(SelectedYearProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedYearProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedYear",
        typeof(int),
        typeof(CustomizableDatePicker));

    #endregion
```